# Understanding code block from XV6 makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu, xv6

I'm trying to understand the following code block from XV6 makefile :

```
ULIB = ulib.o usys.o printf.o umalloc.o

_%: %.o $(ULIB)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o $@ $^
    $(OBJDUMP) -S $@ > $*.asm
    $(OBJDUMP) -t $@ | sed '1,/SYMBOL TABLE/d; s/ .* / /; /^$$/d' > $*.sym
```

Where can I find a reference which explains all the options described above ? For  example I tried to look for the option "-N" in the GNU website and I didn't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on Makefiles, but you're probably looking for the `man` pages of a couple of GNU programs.
This line, for example:

```
$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o $@ $^
```

Is, if I understand it right, a mixture of `bash` and `make` syntax:

- `$(LD)` is replaced by the `make` variable `LD`, which most likely holds the name of the linker executable (usually `ld`).
- `$(LDFLAGS)` is like the above, with the difference that it holds the **flags** to pass to the executable named in `LD`.
- `-N -e main -Ttext 0 -o` are just arguments to `LD`
- `$@` is replaced by the target
- `$^` is replaced by a space-separated list of all dependencies

So if you want to know about the `-N` option, your best bet is the [GNU ld man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> **-N**
>   **--omagic**
>   Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable. Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against shared libraries. If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "OMAGIC". Note: Although a writable text section is allowed for PE-COFF targets, it does not conform to the format specification published by Microsoft.

Comment: Is there someway I can debug this peace of code to understand exactly what it does?

Comment: What is there to debug? Just read the `man` pages of the different commands or google them. But the first command links the target, the second one disassembles it and the third one dumps its symbol table.